# SHA-1 for a submit to github

Tags: git, github

I created a project at

https://github.com/abhitechdojo/ProgrammingAssignment2

I also successfully pushed the code to the repository and can see my code in the browser.

but how do I determine "SHA-1 hash identifier corresponding to the commit that contains the full submission"

I lurked around in the UI but didn't find any SHA-1 corresponding to my push

Comment: https://github.com/abhitechdojo/ProgrammingAssignment2/commits/master

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The UI displays an abbreviated sha as a link to your latest commit.

[image: Imgur]

If you click on it, you'll be redirected to the following url

- https://github.com/abhitechdojo/ProgrammingAssignment2/commit/1b037f69e209e0b71538e7048c88d78e30c32714

Where `1b037f69e209e0b71538e7048c88d78e30c32714` is your full commit sha